# Can I use const to assign jQuery or should I use let?

Tags: javascript, jquery, constants

When I save a jQuery result to a variable so that I can reuse it later, can I declare that variable `const`? Or is there something about the internal workings of jQuery that makes it better for me to use `let`?

```js
const $myDiv = $("#myDiv"); // will I be sorry later that I used const instead of let?
$myDiv.doThing1();
$myDiv.doThing2();
```

Comment: Well are you going to store something else into `$myDiv`? If yes.... let... if no.. const

Comment: There is nothing jquery (or anything else) can do that will cause using const to throw an error. Only you can cause the error, by re-assigning it later.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `const` is perfectly acceptable. The main reason you'd use `let` instead would be if you wanted to reassign `$myDiv`, something like:

```js
let $myDiv = $("#myDiv"); // will I be sorry later that I used const instead of let?
$myDiv.doThing1();

$myDiv = $("#myOtherDiv") // this will break if $myDiv is a const
$myDiv.doThing2();
```

When `$myDiv` is a `const`, it doesn't prevent you from mutating it, just from reassigning it.

Answer (score -1):

This really only comes down to whether or not you intend to store other information to `$myDiv`.

If not, then continue to use `const`. If yes, you should use `let`.